# Downgrading gbm, "Generalized Boosted Regression Models" package

Tags: r

I'm using RStudio, I've just updated gbm package.
With the older version of [gbm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gbm/) when I run this command:

```
model <- gbm(as.formula(myForm), data=mydata, n.trees=2000, cv.folds=5, distribution='multinomial')
```

I was able to see an output like this:

```
Iter   TrainDeviance   ValidDeviance   StepSize   Improve
     1        0.6931             nan     0.0010    0.0004
     2        0.6929             nan     0.0010    0.0004
     3        0.6926             nan     0.0010    0.0004
     4        0.6923             nan     0.0010    0.0004
    ...
```

Now I need to set the parameter `VERBOSE=TRUE` to see that. Also there is **NO output** of the cv.folds! (Number of cross-validation folds to perform). Its like it doesn't get executed. Thirdly `predict.gbm` gives a different output. And finally, its slower.

I would like to downgrade this package to the [version 2.08](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gbm/) but I get this error:

```
Fatal: 'adaboost.o' does not exist - don't know how to make it
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'gbm'
```

I would like to know if there is any way around this error so I can successfully downgrade it, or if I am doing something else wrong. Thank you in advance for your help and guidance.

Comment: What platform are you on? Have you installed all the necessary tools for your platform that allow you to build packages from source (that require compilation)?

Comment: Hi Joran, I'm on Windows 7, 64bit. I thought that all I need to do is download the package and point to the path through the "Install Packages"->"Package Archive File". I do this wrong.. don't I?

Comment: Start [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset). I'm not on Windows, but my understanding is that you have to follow the instructions there _exactly_ and very, very carefully. Good luck.

Comment: If you have read the current version of the help page for `gbm` and there's no mention of `cv.folds` , then you should contact the package maintainer directly to see what and why it has changed. Beyond that, the fact that `predict.gbm` output has "changed" doesn't necessarily mean the new version is wrong. Perhaps an error or a precision limit in the previous version was corrected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install packages from source on Windows you need a reasonably elaborate set of tools. This is documented fully [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html#The-Windows-toolset), but as it says there, be sure to follow the instructions to the letter.